# The best/cheapest way to get money from Moldova to pay bills in UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, banking, international-transfer, money-laundering

I would like to withdraw money from my foreign account outside Europe (Chișinău (Moldova)) and deposit it in a UK bank account, as it has become clear I will be staying in the UK for a longer time than expected. To make money transfer costs a lot as I have to pay commission from my home country and the UK bank will also get a commission.

I opened an account with NatWest and unfortunately they cannot physically book me for an appointment due to corona virus. I called them last Wednesday and they say that bank transfer from foreign countries will attract a commission.

A cheaper option would be withdrawing with an ATM and depositing to my account then I can pay water, electricity bills, and rent using a bank transfer while I look for a job, and importantly to have proof that I have paid rent as I don't trust the kind of receipts my landlord is issuing me.

Yesterday I received an ATM card from my foreign bank account which I had requested and they only charge a very small amount for withdrawals which is very convenient for me. What I want to ask is, do I need to declare the money or will I get taxed by the UK Gov?

If I show the bank my withdrawal slips and the bank statement, will they bank the money without incurring extra charges?

Thanks